# Exporting data from python to glade gui

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk, glade

I am trying to export some data like the name of the user to the gui  when user pressed login button and username and password are correct... all i want to know is a procedure to export data from this code to the gui like inspite of "Welcome" in the object "boxWelcome" i want to display "welcome $username"   (below is my python code nd this is my glade file http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12934567/Login.glade)

```
import sys
try:  
    import pygtk  
    pygtk.require("2.0")  
except:  
    pass  
try:  
    import gtk
except:  
    print("GTK Not Availible")
    sys.exit(1)

class login:

    def __init__( self):
        return None

    def giveResult( self,username,password ):
        print username
        if username == nitin and password == sharma:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

class loginGui:

    def __init__( self ):
        self.builder = gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file("Login.glade")

        dic = { 
            "on_buttonExit_clicked" : self.exit,
            "on_buttonLogin_clicked" : self.checkLogin,
            "on_windowMain_destroy" : self.exit,
         }

        self.builder.connect_signals( dic )

    def checkLogin(self, widget):        
        username = self.builder.get_object ("entryUsername")
        password = self.builder.get_object ("entryPassword")
        try:           
            if (username.get_text() == 'nitin' and password.get_text()== 'sharma'):
                        self.builder.get_object("boxWelcome").show()
                        self.builder.get_object ("boxWarning").hide()
            else:
                        self.builder.get_object("boxWarning").show()
                        self.builder.get_object ("boxWelcome").hide()
        except ValueError:
            #self.builder.get_object("hboxWarning").show()
            #self.builder.get_object("entryResult").set_text("ERROR")
            return 0      

        #self.builder.get_object("hboxWarning").hide()
        #self.builder.get_object("image1").hide()
        #self.builder.get_object("entryResult").set_text(thistime.giveResult())

    def exit(self, widget):
        sys.exit(0)

loginGui = loginGui()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: Nobody will be able to answer this without your Glade file.

Comment: here is my glade file... http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12934567/Login.glade

Comment: @nitinsh99: It is better to post the actaul contents of the file rather than providing a link. It may be a good idea to post your glade file as well instead of linking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why won't You just set it before showing it?
`self.builder.get_object("boxWelcome").set_text("Welcome %s!" % (username.get_text()))`